# Want to use fixed number of Images in Gridview

Tags: android

I am getting arrayIndexOutOfBound Exception if size of array is zero in adapter,giving error in line  `holder.checkbox.setChecked(bmpArray.get(position).isChecked());`

```
package com.algosoft.zobazar;    

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.algosoft.library.GridItem;
import com.algosoft.library.ImageData;
import com.algosoft.library.ImageLoader;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Created by ADMIN on 4/9/2016.
 */
public class GridSellerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ImageData> bmpArray;
    private ImageLoader2 imageLoader;
    private int width;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    protected int visibleFlag;
    public boolean longFlag;
    public HashMap<String, String> hmp;
    private LinearLayout btnDeleteLayout;
    private boolean loadAll = false;
    public GridSellerAdapter(Activity camera, ArrayList<ImageData>        selectedSongs, LinearLayout btnDeleteLayout) {
        super(camera, R.layout.activity_seller__upload_product);
        this.context = camera;
        this.bmpArray = selectedSongs;
        this.btnDeleteLayout = btnDeleteLayout;
        width = ScreenDensity.Width(context);
        imageLoader =  new ImageLoader2(camera.getApplicationContext(),width/3,width/3);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        visibleFlag = View.GONE;
        longFlag = false;
        hmp = new HashMap<String, String>();
        btnDeleteLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


    public void setTrue(){
        loadAll = true;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(loadAll)  return bmpArray.size();
        return 3;

    }
    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageview;
        CheckBox checkbox;
        int id;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.multiple_files_choice, null);
            holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
            holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.checkbox.setId(position);
        holder.imageview.setId(position);
        holder.checkbox.setTag(position);
        holder.imageview.setTag(position);
        holder.checkbox.setTag(position);
        holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(null);
        holder.imageview.setOnLongClickListener(null);
        holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(bmpArray.get(position).isChecked());
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(bmpArray.get(position).getPath(), holder.imageview);
        holder.id = position;
        holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(longFlag){
                    if(!holder.checkbox.isChecked()){
                        holder.checkbox.setChecked(true);
                        hmp.put(bmpArray.get(position).getPath(), bmpArray.get(position).getPath());
                        if(hmp.size()>0)
                            btnDeleteLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }else{
                        holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
                        hmp.remove(bmpArray.get(position));
                        if(hmp.size()<1)
                            btnDeleteLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    Intent i = new Intent(context, MyGallery.class);
                    i.putExtra("position", position);
                    context.startActivity(i);
                    ((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left );
                }
            }
        });
        holder.imageview.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(!longFlag){
                    hmp.clear();
                    holder.checkbox.setChecked(true);
                    hmp.put(bmpArray.get(position).getPath(), bmpArray.get(position).getPath());
                    longFlag = true;
                    visibleFlag = View.VISIBLE;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        holder.checkbox.setVisibility(visibleFlag);
        holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
                bmpArray.get(getPosition).setChecked(buttonView.isChecked());
                if(isChecked){
                    hmp.put(bmpArray.get(position).getPath(), bmpArray.get(position).getPath());
                    if(hmp.size()>0)
                        btnDeleteLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else{
                    hmp.remove(bmpArray.get(position).getPath());
                    if(hmp.size()<1)
                        btnDeleteLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the size of bmpArray ? how you used `setTrue()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(loadAll)  return bmpArray.size();
        return 3;
}
```

it should be **`return 0`** instead of **`return 3`**

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(loadAll)  return bmpArray.size();
            return 0;
}
```

else if you have definite value in `bmpArray` directly use `return bmpArray.size()`

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return null != bmpArray ? bmpArray.size() : 0;
}
```

Or if you are setting `loadAll` from it's `Fragment` or `Activity` then you should use `GridSellerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` instead of updating values in `getCount()`. But after values of `bmpArray` has been changed from its `Activity` or `Fragment` where you are loading its value.

Comment: How i can fix size of gridview to three,if i remove return 3.

Comment: Means you want to discard all values beyond 3??

Comment: for better understanding update xml file code please.. I think you can set android:numColumns="3" in xml file

Comment: If that 3 is for column count then in XML you can use android:numColumns="3"

Comment: yes i want that gridview dont show more than 3 images

Comment: then in getCount() method make it as 
return bmpArray.size() > 3 ? 3 : bmpArray.size();

Answer (score 0):

In getCount() method you written condition like that.

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(loadAll)  return bmpArray.size();
    return 3;

}
```

If loadall is true/false the bmpArray should not be null. Based on loadall value you are trying to loading the values. If loadall value is set false then you were trying to loading limited values.Always you should have the values in bmpArrray.

Check the condition like this..

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(loadAll){
            return bmpArray.size();
    }else{
        if(bmpArray.size()<3){

              return bmpArray.size();
           }else{
                  return 3;
           }

        }
}
```